# Como recarregar um AngularComponent quando navego para a mesma rota?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routes

Estou fazendo um projeto de escola, e nele tenho uma navbar que possue vários botões com **routerLinks** do angular, quando clico neles, me levam para uma rota com o `path: 'busca/:type/:id'`. Quando essa rota é acessada eu uso ngOnInit do componente para fazer uma uma requisição para minha API através de um AngularService. Porém quando eu clico em um outro botão da minha navbar que leva para a mesma rota, porém com o `/:id diferente`, ele não faz a busca pois o componente já está carregado e o ngOnInit não é disparado.
Já tentei a seguinte solução, não funcionou (ou eu não soube realizar corretamente):

Informar onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' na configuração do router module

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})],
 exports: [RouterModule],
})
```

Informar runGuardsAndResolvers: 'paramsChange' na configuração da rota.

Usar o evento navigationEnd na classe

```
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
  ) {
    this.router.events.subscribe((e: any) => {
      if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.getAll();
      }
    });
  }

  getAll(): void {
    // Busca na api
  }
}
```

Comment: Olha realmente ta bem difícil de entender!

Answer (score 1):

Tive o mesmo problema, o que resolveu foi utilizar o **[RouteReuseStrategy](https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy)**, aonde podemos personalizar se uma rota é reutilizada ou não.

O código ficou assim:

```
constructor(
   private router: Router
) {}
    
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
}
```

Queremos que a rota não seja reutilizada, ou seja, quando clicamos em uma mesma rota mas com id diferente, queremos que recarregue a pagina novamente.

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés se inscrever nos eventos de navegação do router, você pode se inscrever para obter as modificações dos parâmetros da URL.

No ngOnInit, você pode, por exemplo, fazer desta maneira:

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(paramsMap => {
    console.log(`Parâmetro da URL: ${paramsMap.get('id')}`);

    // Faz a consulta na tua API aqui!
    // this.fetchData();
  });
}
```

Sempre que os parâmetros da rota forem modificados, você será notificado.

Montei um exemplo no [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6ststm) demonstrando esse comportamento. Observe no console que irá logar os parâmetros sempre que forem alterados.

Espero ter ajudado.